# require_once problem

Tags: php, autoload, require-once

I have this code in the __constructor

```
  $this->Reliability = new Reliability("name","url");
```

Problem: I got an unexpected strange error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Reliability' not found in "/path/"
```

I'm using the "__autoload" method to call the required classes, but it doesn't work when I'm calling the file in a [ModalBOX](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/) Window. If I request the file outside the ModalBox evrything goes fine :(

Some tricks to fix it?

thank you very much in advance!

**P.S.**

this is the __autoload method:

```
function __autoload($className) { 
  if (file_exists($className . '.php')) {   
      require_once $className . '.php'; 
      return true; 
  }
```

else return false;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your autoloader registered in the file displayed in the modalbox?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but, even if I changed it, I still got that error about the Class not found.

Comment: That means your class is not in the place the autoloader is looking for. Try echoing the filename and path it's calling `file_exists` on, so you can see what it is trying to load.

Comment: Done!
thank you thank you! Sometimes is just a matter of motivation!

(I apologize for my English but it isn't my native language)

See ya ;)